# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch [ Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms ]

Tags: elastic, kibana, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch-oss 7.9.2 and kibana 7.9.2 on ubuntu 18.04 when I start elasticsearch service then it's started normally but when I start service kibana it's not starting and shows error '**Unable to connect to Elasticsearch**. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following setting in `/etc/elasticsearch.yml` and it will work.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node
```